# What is the adjective for a collection or multiset of numbers that add up to 100%?

Tags: terminology

E.g. {0.2, 0.7, 0.1}.
Would be used in a phrase like "Verify that the weights are [adjective, that add to 100%]."

Comment: Is "complementary" the appropriate term here?

Comment: I've been using the term "probability vector" for a vector $x \in \mathbb R^K$ with nonnegative components which sum to $1$. It's very useful in machine learning to have a name for this type of vector.